# How to store two bytes in a BYTE array as an int (or something similar)?

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I am writing a bittorrent client in C++ that receives a message from a tracker (server) containing several 6 byte strings. The first 4 bytes represent the IP address of a peer and the next 2 bytes represent the port number that the peer is listening on.

I have worked out how to convert the ip bytes into a human readable ip address but am struggling to convert the two bytes representing the port number into an int (or something similar)

Here are my efforts so far:

```
BYTE portbinary[2];
unsigned short peerport;

//trackers[i]->peersBinary[j * 6 + 4] is the first byte
portbinary[0] = trackers[i]->peersBinary[j * 6 + 4];
//trackers[i]->peersBinary[j * 6 + 5] is the second byte
portbinary[1] = trackers[i]->peersBinary[j * 6 + 5];
peerport = *portbinary;
```

Upon examination peerport only seems to contain the integer representation of the first byte, how might I be able to fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using bitwise operations instead of type punning because it brings no issues with endianness at all (the port number comes as a big endian number, and many systems today are little endian).

```
int peerport = (portbinary[0] << 8) | portbinary[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like the data is aligned, you can just use

```
peerport = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)(trackers[i]->peersBinary + j * 6 + 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `portbinary` is an array of `BYTE`, then `*portbinary` is equivalent to `portbinary[0]`.

A portable way to to achieve your result could be:

```
peerport = portbinary[0];
peerport = 256*peerport + portbinary[1];
```

This assumes `portbinary` was delivered in network byte order.

Answer (score -1):

Solution with unions:

```
union port_extractor
{
    BYTE raw_port[2];
    unsigned short port_assembled;
};
```

This will work if your computer endianess is the same as of representation you fetch from the network. Sorry, I dont know how it comes by bittorrent protocol.

If the endianess is the opposite, then the solution you are bound to use is not as nice:

```
unsigned short port_assembled = (unsigned short)raw_port[first_byte] | ((unsigned short)raw_port[second_byte] << 8);
// first_byte = 0, second_byte = 1 or vice versa 
// depending on source data endianess
```

Comment: I like this approach as well and do it too. When endianess is not a concern, this works well. When it is a concern, it's best to just use bitwise operators.

Comment: It doesn't depend on system endianness at all. It only depends on the endianness of the source data.